# Searchable method on BelongsTo field does not work in Laravel Nova, not returning any items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

i have a model called **Customer** that has **HasMany** Relatinship to**Notes** model

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

and **Note** has **BelongsTo** relationship to **Customer**

```
public function customer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}
```

then i defined the same relationship in **Note** nova resource

```
BelongsTo::make('Customer', 'customer', Customer::class)
```

until here every thing works perfectly now if want to call `->searchable()` on BelongsTo field it doesn't  return any thing from search

```
BelongsTo::make('Customer', 'customer', Customer::class)->searchable()
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field that you call srearchable() on must be in search array in your resource.

so if your field is BelogsTo you must put the **title** field of the resource that you are belonging to into sreach array

in my case the title field is

```
public static $title = 'name';
```

so i put it in

```
public static $search = [
    'id',
    'name',
];
```

and every thing works as expected

Answer (score 2):

Your **BelongsTo** field is in different table, so if you want to search something in **Note** Resource with **Customer** field your search won't work. In this case I use [SearchesRelations](https://github.com/TitasGailius/nova-search-relations) package for searching. You could install this package and put this code in your **Resource** class

```
  public static $searchRelations = [
    'customer' => ['name', 'another_customer_field'],
];
```

Please check the documentation for more details [SearchesRelations](https://github.com/TitasGailius/nova-search-relations) .

Answer (score 2):

On **Laravel Nova 4**, you can use relationship to do this:

For example, you have **Purchase Orders** and **Suppliers** and want to search for Supplier on Purchase Order Resource:

**PurchaseOrder Model:**

```
public function supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'supplier_id', 'id');
}
```

**PurchaseOrder Nova Resource:**

```
public static $search = [
    'supplier.name',
];
```

You can see more about this on Laravel Nova documentation: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/search/#searching-relationships